# Almost independent Bernoulli variables

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, limit-theorems

There is some global parameter $n\to\infty$.
And a function $N=N(n)\to\infty$.

Let $X^n_1,X^n_2,\ldots,X^n_N$ be independent Bernoulli random variables, where $\delta\le P(X^n_i=1)=1-P(X^n_i=0)\le 1-\delta$ for some $\delta>0$.  Let $S=S(n)=\sum_{i=1}^N X^n_i$.

It is of course standard stuff to find Berry-Esseen-type normal estimates, tail bounds, etc for $S$.

Now say $Y^n_1,Y^n_2,\ldots,Y^n_N$ satisfy the same conditions, except that instead of independence we have the following weaker condition: For any $i_1\lt\cdots\lt i_k$ and any $\boldsymbol c\in\{0,1\}^k$ we have
$$P((Y^n_{i_1},\ldots,Y^n_{i_k})=\boldsymbol c) = P((X^n_{i_1},\ldots,X^n_{i_k})=\boldsymbol c)(1+\Delta),$$
where $\Delta=\Delta(n; i_1,\ldots,i_k)$ satisfies $|\Delta|\le ak/n$ for some global constant $a$. Let $T=T(n)=\sum_{i=1}^N Y^n_i$.

These conditions ensure that as $n\to\infty$, $T$ and $S$ approach the same distribution (after normalizing) as $n\to\infty$ since the $m$-th moments asymptotically agree for any fixed $m$.

What I'd like is explicit tail bounds and or Berry-Esseen-type estimates for $T$.  I feel sure that this, or something perilously close to it, has been worked out before, but the related literature is so vast I can't find it.

EDIT: Anthony Quas has pointed out that these conditions are not enough for the variances of $S$ and $T$ to asymptotically match (for $N\gg n$, which is true in the application), even though the second moments match.  We have to consider what can be salvaged.

Comment: Since one has closeness of all the moments of $T$ to those of the corresponding normal random variable, I suppose one can derive from there, by Taylor's expansion, some closeness between the corresponding characteristic functions, which could then result in a Berry--Esseen-type bound, via an Esseen-type of inequality.

Comment: Yes, that's our backup plan if nobody identifies some existing literature that covers it.

Comment: I guess you need more than  the upper bound from coupling to independent random variables with probabilities shifted up by $a/n$ from the $X_i^n$, and the corresponding lower bound?

Comment: Something is bugging me here. Probably just being stupid, but what's to stop you having $N(n)\gg n$, choosing $Z_1,\ldots,Z_{N/2}$ iid in $\{0,1\}$, choosing $Z_{N/2+i}=1-Z_i$ and then setting the $Y_i$'s to be a random rearrangement of the $Z$'s? If you do this, then for an arbitrary $i_1<\ldots<i_k$, it's very unlikely that you've picked a $Z$ and its twin, so that the finite marginals should be fine. But the sum, $T$ is nowhere close to the normal distribution you get for $S$ (no problem with tail bounds though in this case!)

Comment: @Anthony:  That's a great comment that makes it clear that I hadn't thought about it enough.  The second moments of $S$ and $T$ asymptotically agree, but in order to have the right limit distribution, it is necessary to have the variances agree. Your example shows that the variance of $T$ might converge to almost anything (in your case, 0).  The conditions I wrote are not enough to imply that the variances of $S$ and $T$ match.  Thanks.